# How to get PHP variable data and store it in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php

How would I access a value from PHP, retrieve it, and store it in my JavaScript variable?

**Example:**

```
<?php
   $name = "john"
?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var name = john
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Can all of you guys stop giving the same answer to this question ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $name = 'john';?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';
        alert(name);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $name = "john";
?>

var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>'
```

Comment: If you want to pass string you need to add quotes.

Comment: can we perform it without echo?

Comment: @AjayDude You can't, unless it's with an ajax call and an appropriate php function to return it which is an overkill to display a variable

Comment: @AjayDude as mentioned above, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

If you have any trouble after trying to work on it alone, post another question and i'm sure we'll all help you

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the PHP variable into your javascript while your page is created.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = "<?php echo $name; ?>";
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = "<?=$name;?>";
</script>
```

Of course this is for simple variables and not objects.

Comment: Can we perform it without echo?

Comment: you need to print variable inside php code to fetch that value , so you can not use it without echo or print

Comment: I want to just retrieve name from my php

Answer (score 0):

Generate part of your JavaScript by PHP:

```
<?php
   $name = "john";

   echo "<javascript>var name = \"" . $name . "\";</javascript>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eg.

```
<?php
   $name = "john"
?>

 <script>

 var myJSVar = <?php echo $name; ?>

 alert(myJSVar);

 </script>
```

In the above case, Your PHP variable must have defined before being accessed by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the PHP variable inside a hidden `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="myvar" class="hidden"><?php echo $myphpvar; ?></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {display: none; visibility: hidden;}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var phpvar = document.getElementById('myvar').innerHTML;
```